# Understanding the difference between ~ and -

Tags: terraform

I'm working on importing one of our rds instance into terraform.

Terraform plan shows ~ and -

```
  ~ maintenance_window                    = "sat:06:10-sat:06:40" -> (known after apply)
  - max_allocated_storage                 = 0 -> null
```

Both of these values are not defined in the configuration, I would like to understand, why it is showing - and Do we configure null variables also in the module?

Using Terraform 0.12.28

Comment: The explanation of the symbols is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66836674/understanding-the-difference-between-and).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically:

- `~` the value is in the state and is changing after the plan
- `-` the value is in the state and you are trying to remove it (`null` value)

`maintenance_window` is showing `~` because its value is going to change, and in your specific case its value is computed and hence known after applying the changes. From the docs:

> maintenance_window - (Optional) The window to perform maintenance in. Syntax: "ddd:hh24:mi-ddd:hh24:mi". Eg: "Mon:00:00-Mon:03:00". See RDS Maintenance Window docs for more information.

If that window is fine for you, you can specify that as an argument or let Terraform change it to its default value.

`max_allocated_storage` is showing `-` because when you imported the resource in the state, it imported all Terraform known arguments, but you are not specifying that one. In particular from the docs:

> max_allocated_storage - (Optional) When configured, the upper limit to which Amazon RDS can automatically scale the storage of the DB instance. Configuring this will automatically ignore differences to allocated_storage. Must be greater than or equal to allocated_storage or 0 to disable Storage Autoscaling.

In this case you can set `max_allocated_storage = 0` in order to not show any change in the plan for that argument